# Problem with subclassing richedit using GWL_WNDPROC

Tags: c, winapi, subclassing, richedit, common-controls

I do this exact thing for both edit and richedit but for the latter there is an access violation, why? The same thing happens when done for tabctrl too. What am I doing wrong? How can I get it to work?

```
WNDPROC OriginalProc;

LRESULT CALLBACK MyProc(HWND h, UINT m, WPARAM w, LPARAM p)
{
return OriginalProc (h, m, w, p);// access violation for common controls
}

// elsewhere 
HWND h = CreateWindow(....)
OriginalProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLong(h, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)MyProc);
```

I am using vc++ 6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you perhaps forgotten to call [`InitCommonControlsEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775697%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

You should not call `OriginalProc` directly; use [CallWindowProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633571%28VS.85%29.aspx) to call it instead.

Also, it's hard to tell from the sample you gave, but make sure `OriginalProc` is not being used by multiple windows. It looks here that it's a single global variable, but I'm guessing you're subclassing multiple windows.